# Android Doing file operations async

Tags: android, file, asynchronous, loader

In android is the best practise to do all the hardwork in an seperate thread to never block the ui. Now is my only goal to list all files of an app internal directory like:

```
final File directory = new File( context.getFilesDir(), "images" );
if( !directory.exists() ) {
    directory.mkdirs();
}
return directory.listFiles();
```

Should i do this inside a Loader or AsyncTaskLoader? In my mind pops another question up. I.e. if my Loader listen via FileObserver to directory changes then is this observer build in the main thread and does this like:

```
new FileObserver( new File( context.getFilesDir(), "images" ).getPath() ) ...
```

The directory should then load asynchronous too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing directory files generally is a really fast operation and wouldn't require a background thread.

If you want to listen to file changes, here is the answer on the second part of your question, regarding FileObserver multithreading:

It doesn't matter on which thread you create a `FileObserver`. All work happens on a special FileObserver thread. `onEvent` is called in this special thread. You should then manually handle what thread you need. The `onEvent` docs make it very clear:

> The event handler, which must be implemented by subclasses. This
>   method is invoked on a special FileObserver thread. It runs
>   independently of any threads, so take care to use appropriate
>   synchronization! Consider using Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable) to
>   shift event handling work to the main thread to avoid concurrency
>   problems.